# How to show the formatting suggestions menu while answering or commenting

Tags: support, comments, answers, markdown

I always get the formatting help from SO saying about how to use bold, italics, hyperlinks, etc while I post an answer or comment. But after I closed it once, I no longer get that help. What should I do so that it reappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On answers you can press the "?":

[image]

And on comments you can press the "help" link below "Add Comment":

[image]

Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help